# Firefox issue with full screen slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

At this website, i make a full screen slider.

[Website link](http://media57.nl/drijver5/)

It works well on Chrome and IE, but on firefox, it shows only 50% of the screen.

This is the code i used:

```
   .q_slider {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}
.carousel-inner .slider_content_outer {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 12;
}
```

Did i do something wrong?

Comment: use comma(,) to in between .carousel-inner and .slide_content_outer{....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you remove the following negative margin top values it will work...

[image]